# encapsulamento de um ponto no espaço cartesiano de duas dimensões

Tags: java

Criei uma classe `ponto2d` com os atributos x e y, criei os métodos get e set, até ai blz, depois criei uma classe `retângulo` com largura e altura, necessito saber valor de um ponto no espaço cartesiano de duas dimensões.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Prefira copiar e colar o código. Fica muito mais legível. Além disso, a pergunta não ficou muito clara. Pode explicar melhor? (editando a postagem)

Comment: O que você chama de "valor" do ponto, pra efeitos dessa pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, sua própria classe é um [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), ou seja, é uma classe que usamos para transportar dados de um método para outro, e ao invés de ficarmos passando toda hora X e Y, passando apenas sua classe `ponto2d` como parâmetro.

Uma boa base é a classe [Point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) do próprio JDK: ela mesma representa um ponto e é usada como valor base para um ponto cartesiano por outras classes de geometria.

Ou seja, se você tem um triângulo, terá 3 objetos ponto2d para representar os pontos cartesianos.